# can microservice code be written all-the-way Reactive (if data on the next steps dependent on some data from previous steps)?

Tags: java, spring, netty, reactive, flux

```
       Hello everyone.
```

I'm trying to reach foreseen goal, however without yet full understanding all capabilities of the Java, Lambda, Spring Boot and Reactive programming, which I need to utilize (I'm relatively new, so bare with me). I already wrote 2 separately working microservices using Spring Boot (see diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFDOJ.jpg Microservice #1  - to access Postgres DB's raw data; Microservice #2 - to store preprocessed raw data in REDIS in-memory DB).

**My current foreseen goal is on writing Microservice #3**, which works with both Microservices #1 & #2 as well as to provide some search results to Front-End. All parts utilize REST APIs between them. Microservice #3 (in focus) uses Spring Boot WebFlux & Netty (naturally reactive).
**Current subtask of Microservice #3** is to search items by substring in their name; provide certain preprocessed results (in the form of e.g., Dictionary - Map<String, Object>); and add preprocessed items into in-memory cache, if some items are not yet there.
**Main question #1** - is it possible to make such task all the way reactive from the very beginning (initial request) till the very end (final response)?
For visualization I divided overall task into 6 steps:

1. microservice #3 (in focus) receives REST API request from Front-End (e.g., `http://localhost:1234/search?substring=<substring>`)
2. microservice #3 (in focus) requests data from Postgres DB via microservice #1 using REST API (e.g., `http://localhost:2345/search?substring=<substring>`), receives possibly non-empty list of dictionaries with uniquely identifying values for certain key, e.g., "topicId". I'd like to use reactive  `WebClient` Object
3. microservice #3 (in focus) checks existence of preprocessed items in in-memory cache by single REST API request to microservice #2 (sending list of parameters - "topicID" keys values fetched on previous step #2. Important: I don't want to implement multiple REST API requests per each item ("topicId") not to face accidental spikes in number of simultaneous threads used behind the scenes. Therefore I aggregated "topicId" into a list for REST API request: e.g., `http://localhost:3456/cache?ids=<topicId#1>,<topicId#2>,<topicId#3>,...` 
   Important: in case one or several items were not found microservice #2 put 'null' value in respective place in the REST API answer.
4. [optional step] microservice #3 (in focus) makes some additional requests to Postgres DB to replace 'null' values, if any, with new data-to-be-preprocessed
5. [optional step] microservice #3 (in focus) saves newly preprocessed item(s), if any, into cache '''POST http://localhost:3456/cache/<topicId_intoCache>'''
6. microservice #3 (in focus) returns list of preprocessed items to Front-End as a result of initial request made on step #1.

**Problem statement**:
I read great advice on [stackoverflow's topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73907011/returning-mono-response-from-subscribe-of-mono-fromcallable) "You should not call subscribe inside your Reactor pipeline. Subscribe should be considered a terminal operation that starts the pipeline asynchronously in an unknown time in the future, and should only serve to connect to some other part of your system." My understanding that my Spring Boot's REST controller to make final output data (subscribe) on step #6 upon returning REST API response

@GetMapping(value = "/topics", produces = "application/json")
public Mono<List<Map<String, Object>>> ListTopics(@RequestParam(required = true) Map<String, String> queryParams) { .... }
However, I feel that on Step #3 I need to subscribe on Mono results declared on previous step #2 (step #2 uses WebClient, e.g., '``postgresClient.get().uri(TOPICS_URI_COUNT_TRAILER).retrieve().bodyToMono(List.class);``` )
For the reason to build list of "topicId" values. And this subscription sounds to me like a braking reactive pipeline logic.

If it's still possible to make it reactive, I have
**Extra question #2** : if I have 2 Flux objects (with 1-1 mapping between corresponding elements): 1) Flux<List> (containing "topicId" list); and 2) Flux<List<Map<String, Object>>>; is it a good way to 'combine corresponding values using Flux.zip, e.g.,
Flux.zip(topicIds$, CachedTopics$, (item1, item2) -> {return getTopicAddToCache(item1,item2)}), where function getTopicAddToCache(item1,item2) takes item1 - topicId value and item2 - preprocessed item taken from cache; and returns either item2, if it's value is not 'null'; or preprocessed new item based on "topicId" value?

Thank you,
Alex

### Controller.java:

```
`@GetMapping(value = "/search", produces = "application/json")
public Mono<List<Map<String,Object>>> ListTopics(@RequestParam(required = true) Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    String searchByTopicNameSubstring = queryParams.getOrDefault("substring","?");  // taking value from dictionary for key "substring"
    if (searchByTopicNameSubstring!=null && (!searchByTopicNameSubstring.equals("?"))) {   
        return engineObject.listTopicsBySubstring(searchByTopicNameSubstring);
    }
    throw new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST, "Unexpected query string (with 'key=value' pairs [non-null values]) observed (currently keys are case-sensitive). Expected optional keys: 'substring'. Check query parameters - " + queryParams.toString());
}
`
```

### Engine.java:

```
##private final WebClient postgresClient;


`public Mono<List> listTopicsItems(String topicNameSubstring) {
    try {
        return postgresClient.get()
                .uri(GET_TOPICS_LIST_BY_SUBSTRING_URL_TRAILER)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(List.class);
    }
    catch (WebClientException e){
        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Postgres DB microservice cannot get topic list number; error: "+e.getMessage()));
    }
}
`

public Mono<List<Map<String,Object>>> listTopicsBySubstring(String topicNameSubstring) {
       
     
     // 2.1. send GET REST API Request; e.g., "http://localhost:1234/search?substring=<substring>
     Mono<List> initialList = listTopicsItems(topicNameSubstring);

     // Q1. how to properly handle 'initialList' without invoking initialList.subcribe()
     // to build list of "topicIds" for further single request to REDIS's microservice
     // e.g., http://localhost:3456/cache?ids=12,23,...?
     // any suggestions are welcome. Thanks a lot.
```

Comment: here is a link to the diagram - https://imgur.com/a/xXQz3Hz

Comment: Don't misuse the mono tag, as it is for something else.